# Getting values from JTextField on buttonclick event

Tags: swing, listener, jbutton, actionlistener, jtextfield

I am writing a simple program which takes 3 values from user using 3 `JTextField` and with 2 buttons, one for Chart and other for Graph.

On Click of any of this button, the values taken from the interface, should be returned to the calling function is the requirement.
(i.e. I am calling View from Controller and taking values from user in view and expecting back in controller)
For this i have used `textfield1.getText()` function inside:

```
Button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    //Overriding function over here for getting the data
});
```

event. and at the end I am retuning the `ArrayList` of values taken from user.

However the issue, is as soon as the program i starting to run, it's not waiting for the button click but directly returning the `ArrayList` to the Controller with the default values.

Appreciate any quick help on this..

I am pretty new to listeners and that might be the reason for the issue..

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for better help sooner

Answer (score 3):

The question lacks some code to really pinpoint the problem, but I am under the impression you think that the call

```
do A
button.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
    do C
  }
} );
do B
```

will stop your code execution until the button is pressed. This is incorrect.

In the above snippet, it will do `A`, then attach the listener to the button, and immediately continue with `B`. The listener code will only be triggered when the button is pressed. So `C` is only executed when the button is pressed, which is after `B`.

There is a tutorial about [`ActionListener`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) available on the Oracle site. If you are not familiar with the listener concept as you claim, it might also be helpful to read about the [Observer design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), which is the design pattern you use when you attach a listener.

Comment: Just missed to attach the code,

///Definition of the view (i.e. frame, button, fields etc. creation.
///jb1 button and added listener on it as below

jb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

inputParameters.add(0,Double.parseDouble(a.getText()));
inputParameters.add(1,Double.parseDouble(b.getText()));
inputParameters.add(2,Double.parseDouble(c.getText()));
flag=1;
}
});

Return inputParameters;

However, this is returning the values before the action itself..

Comment: @KunalV That is exactly what I say in my answer. `B` is executed before `C`